# NameError: name 'Radiobutton' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nameerror

I am constructing a messaging application, and using Tkinter for GUI. I am trying to create some buttons, but I receive an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/artur/Documents/MScProject/MSc Project/Task #179276/main_program.py", line 174, in <module>
    app = Application(the_window)

  File "/home/artur/Documents/MScProject/MSc Project/Task #179276/main_program.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.AES_radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = 'AES algorithm', bg = color, variable=self.var, value=0)
NameError: name 'Radiobutton' is not defined
```

I am posting all of the source code here:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar

from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Frame

from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Label


from AESEncDec import *
from MD5Hashing import *
from RSAEncDec import *

color = 'lightblue' #color our background


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.frame_width = 700
        self.frame_height = 400

        # Set configuration our frame
        self.config(width = self.frame_width, height = self.frame_height, bg = color) 
        self.pack()

        # Create textBox for input data
        self.textbox_one = Text()
        self.textbox_one.place(x = 30, y = 170, height = 200, width = 300 )

        # Create textBox for result
        self.textbox_two = Text()
        self.textbox_two.place(x = 370, y = 170, height = 200, width = 300 )

        label_input_text = Label( text = "Input text: ", bg = color)
        label_input_text.place(x = 30, y = 155, height = 10, width = 70 )

        label_output_text = Label( text = "Result: ", bg = color)
        label_output_text.place(x = 370, y = 155, height = 10, width = 50 )

        # IntVar help to detect, what radioButton was chosen
        self.var = IntVar()

        # Create radioButton for AES
        self.AES_radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = 'AES algorithm', bg = color, variable=self.var, value=0)
        self.AES_radiobutton.place(x = 100, y = 20, height = 30, width = 100 )

        # Create radioButton for DSA
        self.DSA_radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = 'DSA algorithm', bg = color, variable=self.var, value=1)
        self.DSA_radiobutton.place(x = 100, y = 70, height = 30, width = 100 )

        # Create radioButton for Hash function
        self.HF_radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = 'Hash function', bg = color, variable=self.var, value=2)
        self.HF_radiobutton.place(x = 100, y = 120, height = 30, width = 100 )

        # Create label
        self.lable_for_ask_bits = Label(text = 'Input size of bits:', bg = color)
        self.lable_for_ask_bits.place(x = 210, y = 70, height = 30, width = 100 )

        # Create textBox for input bits
        self.input_bits = Text()
        self.input_bits.place(x = 310, y = 75, height = 20, width = 50 )
        self.input_bits.insert(INSERT, '16')

        # Create button to encrypt text
        self.encrypt_button = Button(root, text = "Encrypt text", command = self.encrypt_text)
        self.encrypt_button.place(x = 420, y = 20, height = 80, width = 100 )

        # Create button to decrypt text
        self.decrypt_button = Button(root, text = "Decrypt text", command = self.decrypt_text)
        self.decrypt_button.place(x = 540, y = 20, height = 80, width = 100 )

        # Create button to hash
        self.hash_button = Button(root, text = "Hash text", command = self.hashing )
        self.hash_button.place(x = 420, y = 120, height = 30, width = 220)

        # Create AES object, keyword "this is a very strong key"
        # You can change keyword
        self.AES = AESEncDec('this is a very strong key')

        # Save bits
        self.bit_length = 16
        # Create RSA object
        self.RSA = RSAEncDec(self.bit_length)


    def encrypt_text(self):
        self.textbox_two.delete("1.0", END)
        # Get radioButton selection
        selection = self.var.get()
        # if chosen AES
        if selection == 0:
            # Read text from input
            message = self.textbox_one.get("1.0", END)
            encrypt_message = self.AES.encrypt(message)
            # Output result
            self.textbox_two.insert(INSERT, encrypt_message)
        # if chosen RSA
        elif selection == 1:
            try:
                # Read number of bits
                tmp_bits = int(self.input_bits.get("1.0", END))
                # if bits not in range from 4 to 32 print error message
                if tmp_bits < 4 or tmp_bits > 32:
                    tkMessageBox.showerror(message ='Bits must be in range from 4 to 32')
                else:
                    # else, if tmp_bits not = self.bit_length: create new object
                    if tmp_bits != self.bit_length:
                        self.bit_length = tmp_bits
                        self.RSA = RSAEncDec(self.bit_length)
            except:
                tkMessageBox.showerror(message ='You must input integer number')

            # Find max number
            max_number = self.RSA.get_max_value_to_encrypt()

            try:
                # Read text from input (myst be number)
                message = int(self.textbox_one.get("1.0", END))
                if message < 0 or message > max_number:
                    tkMessageBox.showerror(message ='Input text must be number in range from 0 to ' + str(max_number))
                else:
                    encrypt_message = self.RSA.encrypt(message)
                    # Output result
                    self.textbox_two.insert(INSERT, encrypt_message)
            except:
                tkMessageBox.showerror(message ='Input text must be number in range from 0 to ' + str(max_number))
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(message ='You must select "AES" or "RSA" radioButton')


    def decrypt_text(self):
        self.textbox_two.delete("1.0", END)
        # Get radioButton selection
        selection = self.var.get()
        # if chosen AES
        if selection == 0:
            # Read text from input
            message = self.textbox_one.get("1.0", END)
            decrypt_message = self.AES.decrypt(message)
            # Output result
            self.textbox_two.insert(INSERT, decrypt_message)
        elif selection == 1:
            # Read text from input
            message = int(self.textbox_one.get("1.0", END))
            decrypt_message = self.RSA.decrypt(message)
            # Output result
            self.textbox_two.insert(INSERT, decrypt_message)
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(message ='You must select "AES" or "RSA" radioButton')

    def hashing(self):
        # Get radioButton selection
        selection = self.var.get()
        # if chosen Hash function
        if selection == 2:
            # Read text from input
            message = self.textbox_one.get("1.0", END)
            # Hashing
            hashing_message = Hashing(message)
            # Output result
            self.textbox_two.insert(INSERT, hashing_message)
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(message ='You must select "Hash function" radioButton')


#create object TK class
the_window = tk.Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
#create object Application
app = Application(the_window)
#run our Application
app.mainloop()
```

I still see the GUI though and an input box, but a lot of elements are missing. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Don't you just need to import RadiaButton from tkinter?!

Comment: you've posted many questions about the same issue, why don't you use the suggested syntax to call module components : `tkinter.RadioButton` or `tk.RadioButton` if you defined an alias?

Comment: it would be great to specify at what place exactly should I call this and how it should look like, because my attempts don't work :(

Comment: everywhere you need a RadioButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple import of Radiobutton module solved the issue

Comment: You can import every objects from the module `tkinter` like so, but if you use many of them, the import statements will be as long as your code. You can avoid all this imports by just importing `tkinter` and then use `tkinter.Label` or `tkinter.RadioButton`. What matters is that you need to tell Python where it can find the object you need.